# Using generic type of interface in method

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm getting confused with generics in Kotlin. How can I use T type of Class  in function parameters (in addNewItem() and deleteItem())? I'm getting error "Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position kotlin"

```
interface IStorageManager<out T: IFileItem> {

fun getAllItems(): List<T>

fun addNewItem(itemToAdd: T)

fun deleteItem(itemToDelete: T)

}
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ0pH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your interface only produces `T`, you can make this clear to the compiler by annotating it with `out`. In your example you also have methods that act as consumers of `T`, thus `out` does not work. Just remove the `out` keyword and all will work fine.

This is a good reference:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html